# Can we reference custom settings in the Head Markup?

Tags: community, community-builder, experience-builder-page

In the Salesforce Community Page, under Experience Builder--> Settings-->Advance-->Head Markup, can we reference custom settings there? or global variables?

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_page_head.htm&type=5

[image]

[image]